# Permission denied when trying to use cargo with docker

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, permission-denied, rust-cargo

I have a docker container built from the following image : FROM debian:9.11-slim

I try to install rust using the following line in my Dockerfile and it works fine until the last line. I get a permission denied error whenever I try to run /rust/cargo. However, if I connect to the container and run it from there via the command line it works. However, I need to be able to run rust/cargo commands from the docker file. Any help?

```
ENV RUSTUP_HOME=/rust/rustup
ENV CARGO_HOME=/rust/cargo
RUN set -eux; \
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rust-lang/rustup/1.22.1/rustup-init.sh"; \
wget -O rustup-init.sh "$url"; \
echo "b273275cf4d83cb6b991c1090baeca54 rustup-init.sh" | md5sum -c -; \
echo "8928261388c8fae83bfd79b08d9030dfe21d17a8b59e9dcabda779213f6a3d14 rustup-            init.sh" | sha256sum -c -; \
bash ./rustup-init.sh --profile=minimal -y -t thumbv7em-none-eabihf; \
rm rustup-init.sh; \
chmod -R go+rwX /rust; \
/rust/cargo --version
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `chmod -R go+rwX`

How to reproduce:

We have `file`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo good
```

```
~ $ ls -l file
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Jun 30 11:49 file
~ $ ./file
-bash: ./file: Permission denied
~ $ chmod go+rwX file
~ $ ls -l file
-rw-rw-rw-  1 user  staff  23 Jun 30 11:50 file
~ $ ./file
-bash: ./file: Permission denied
```

As you can see `-rw-rw-rw-` permissions don't allow to execute file

Solution is to use something of below:

- `chmod -R ug+rwx /rust` (add all permissions to user and group)
- `chmod -R ugo+rwx /rust` (add all permissions to all users)
- `chmod -R 777 /rust` (add all permissions to all users (same as ugo+rwx))
- `chmod -R 755 /rust` (add execution permissions to all users)
- `chmod 755 /rust/cargo` (add execution permissions to all users only for execution file)
- *[if permissions already correct]* don't set permissions at all (remove `chmod -R go+rwX /rust`) ← Best way

Comment: `rustup` should already have set the correct permissions so there should be no need for the `chmod` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but in a slightly different situation. I was using docker-compose pipeline in GitHub actions on EC2 [Self-Hosted Runner](https://docs.github.com/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners), based on the native GitHub pipeline. I didn't remove the Rust toolchain installation, which caused reinstallation of cargo in every build on EC2 instance changing permissions and sourcing binaries from cargo `source ~/.cargo/env`, hence the permission error on the default system user.

In my case, the solution was simply removing the installation of Rust from the workflow.yml and sourcing the system rust `source ~/.bashrc`.